# Media queries for desktop only work once

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a responsive fixed width layout that once you reach its width switches to new styles and then once reaching mobile type sizes changes again. If I resize my browser window it works properly for the first "break point" but the second just resorts to the initial set of styles with overflow hidden. I know my small screen styles work because I've tested them on my Android and with Chrome emulation. Why then please, do they not kick in on the desktop browser?

In HTML

```
<HTML>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
</HTML>
```

In CSS

```
/* FULL SCREEN DESKTOP STYLES*/
{
...
}

/* Tablet (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 561px) 
and (max-width : 1024px) 
{
TABLET AND BROWSER HALF SCREEN STYLES
}

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 560px) 
{
SMALL SCREEN STYLES
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Kolkurtz

Comment: Your all media queries are the same. Are you sure about it?

Comment: Also do you need portrait and landscape media controller as an aswer?

Comment: ...and `maximum-scale=1` is not recommended...some of us *need* to be able to scale up. We're not all blessed with perfect eyesight.

Comment: Sorry, yes there were two different media queries. I have edited. Not sure what you mean in your second comment guven.

Comment: Paulie, if you press control you can use your mouse wheel to zoom in a webpage.

Comment: You may want to leave min-device-width off the smallest sryle. Otherwise, it will use the default largest style, below 320px.

Comment: I've removed the below 320px rule. This still doesn't affect the browser render. I've checked which CSS rules are loading in Chrome Dev and below 560px the browser is using the main rules.

Comment: Sorry folks I've wasted your time. I was combining min-width and min-device width. Now fixed. Min-device width wasn't applying to desktop.